# Does Alchemy have a list of combinations you're already tried?

Tags: graveyard-keeper

Alchemy is meant to be done by trial and error. When I first unlocked alchemy, I tried a bunch of combinations at random, but I don't remember which combinations I already tried.

Is there any list of combinations you've already tried anywhere in the game?

Answer (score 1):

No, it only keeps the successful formulas.